Network Manager not working
Very green Ubuntu user here (24.04.1 LTS). I’ve had it for a little over a year, but I’m still not comfortable making changes to the base system, and always have to research on how to even install apps.
I was having lagging WiFi issues a few days ago (1 bar on laptop, while full bars on my iPhone and work phone), so I started looking for solutions. I found a few, and tried some, but nothing worked. I’m guessing one of them required a reboot, because I left my laptop unplugged and running overnight, and the battery died. When I rebooted, there’s no WiFi, and I get Network Unavailable and Network Manager not running messages under settings. I’ve run several different commands to restart, and when I run sudo service network-manager status I get Unit network-manager.service could not be found.
The only thing I remember trying was
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf and changing the value from 3 to 2, but I don’t know how to change it back.
Any help on how to troubleshoot would be amazing
Update:
$ systemctl status NetworkManager
NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled, preset: enabled)
    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-10-29 19:40:16 EDT; 19h ago
      Docs: man: NetworkManager(8)
    Process: 1784 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Main PID: 1784 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) CPU: 36ms 

Oct 29 19:40:16 spin-sp315-51 systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Oct 29 19:40:16 spin-sp315-51 systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 29 19:40:16 spin-sp315-51 systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 29 19:40:16 spin-sp315-51 systemd[1]: Failed to start NetworkManager.service Network Manager.

$ lshw -C network
*-network DISABLED 
    description: Wireless interface
    product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
    vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
    logical name: wlp1s0
    version: 31
    serial: 94:e9:79:cc:49:ef
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=6.8.0-47-generic firmware WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 la
    resources: irg:134 memory:b1000000-b11fffff

Ran: journalctl -xeu Networkmanager.service



No entries - -



I could really use some help here. I have a lot of video saved on my drive, and I’m really trying to avoid a fresh install, but I don’t know what else to do here, and this seems like something that some of the pros in here can hemp me troubleshoot

Network Manager service is named NetworkManager. Therefore, to check on its status, run systemctl status NetworkManager.service

Not sure what I’m looking for, but the highlighted lines say Active: failed (Result: exit code), Process: 1784 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/NetworkManager  - -no-daemon (code=exited, status=1/failure), networkmanager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter at 5, Srart request repeated too quickly, Failed with result ‘exit-code’, Failed to start NetworkManager.service - Network Manager

Forgive me, but I have to manually type everything out from my phone

NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled, preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-10-29 19:40:16 EDT; 19h ago
Docs: man: NetworkManager(8)
Process: 1784 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) Main PID: 1784 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
CPU: 36ms

Oct 29 19:40:16 spin-sp315-51 systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Oct 29 19:40:16 spin-sp315-51 systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 29 19:40:16 spin-sp315-51 systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. Oct 29 19:40:16 spin-sp315-51 systemd[1]: Failed to start NetworkManager.service Network Manager.

This is what I get when I run $ lshw -C-network
*-network DISABLED
description: Wireless interface
product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
logical name: wlp1s0
version: 31
serial: 94:e9:79:cc:49:ef
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=6.8.0-47-generic firmware WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 la
resources: irg:134 memory:b1000000-b11fffff

Please update your question with the output of journalctl -xeu NetworkManager.service. Do not add to comments. Comments are for others to ask you questions.
